# Adding Chapters to video as I would for aac

Tags: video, aac, chapters

With AAC I can add section breaks to my audio so if I hit next track it jumps to the next section not to the next file in the playlist.  Is there a way to implement this in the video files I am encoding for iPad/iPod?  I am working on moving an audio podcast to video and would like to continue to have the section markers.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Chapterize 1.0** . Download Link and  Description  [**here**](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Audio/Chapterize.shtml)